# how to remove None (null) values from graphite result

Tags: grafana, graphite

I'm trying to show at time series that has a lot of missing data points as a table in grafana and I get a lot of - results that correlate with nulls.

Is there a way to tell graphite to not return data points with a value of null?

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24217018/589525 It helped me

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in small time slots in graphite datastore and large time between neighbor metrics due to rare updates.

As work around, you may apply **movingAverage(10min)** function in query, where **10min** is update interval of metric.